# How to fix the size of cells in a tablelayout in android

Tags: android, tablelayout, imagebutton

How do you fix(prevent them from moving) the size of cells in a tablelayout in android?

I have a tablelayout with image buttons inside each cell, the problem is, when I change (or remove) the image, the size of the button changes. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Set each View’s layout_width equal to 0.
Add in each View layout_weight, according to your needs

Reference : http://pournaras.zilsen.com/2010/11/01/fixed-column-width-in-tablelayout/